# Change fc-today background color

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui, fullcalendar, sx

I've only found dated responses for this question. I'm trying to change the highlighted background for today. I have the `<FullCalendar>` component inside `<Box>`:

```
<Box flex={"1 1 100%"} ml={"15px"}>
    <FullCalendar
        height={"75vh"}
        plugins={[
            dayGridPlugin,
            timeGridPlugin,
            interactionPlugin,
            listPlugin
        ]}
        headerToolbar={{
            left: "prev,next today",
            center: "title",
            right: "dayGridMonth,timeGridWeek,timeGridDay,listMonth"
        }}
        initialView={"dayGridMonth"}
        editable={true}
        selectable={true}
        selectMirror={true}
        dayMaxEvents={true}
        select={handleDateClick}
        eventClick={handleEventClick}
        eventsSet={(events) => setCurrentEvents(events)}
        initialEvents={[
            {
                id: "aapl_q1_2023",
                title: "AAPL Q1 2023",
                date: "2023-02-02"
            },
            {
                id: "amzn_q4_2023",
                title: "AMZN Q4 2023",
                date: "2023-02-02"
            },
        ]}
        sx={{
            "& .fc-today": {
                backgroundColor: `${colors.redAccent[500]} !important`
            }
        }}
    />
</Box>
```

I'm able to manually change the color by toggling the [css](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fsClC.png) line item

But the `sx` isn't overriding it:

```
sx={{
    "& .fc-today": {
        backgroundColor: `${colors.redAccent[500]} !important`
    }
}}
```

Comment: Does `FullCalendar` have an `sx` prop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that `FullCalendar` accepts a CSS variable `--fc-today-bg-color` for customizing background color of "today", according to their customization [guide](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/css-customization).

If the preference is to use a custom color defined with MUI, perhaps try set the CSS variable with a `sx` prop on the MUI `Box` containing `FullCalendar`.

Minimized live example: [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vitejs-vite-8aikoy?file=src/App.jsx)

Example:

```
<Box sx={{ ["--fc-today-bg-color"]: pink[500] }}>
  <FullCalendar />
</Box>
```

Setting this by `sx` prop on `FullCalendar` itself could also work if the component has already been wired up with MUI by its `styled()` utility.

Comment: John Li! I owe you my life